# Do Boundary Conditions depend on spin connections for gauge fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory

In the article [arXiv:1206.5642](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5642), which talks about gauge fields in conical spacetime, I came across the statement in footnote 4 that the boundary conditions on the gauge field depend on the spin connections on the cone. How to see this? Is it true for any curved spacetime?

Comment: _Which article?_

Comment: See footnote 4 of 1206.5642.

Comment: I read that footnote as referring to a boundary condition on the scalar field $\phi$, not on the gauge field $A$.  Presumably it means that $\phi$ has to have appropriate periodicity in the $\psi$ angular variable in the conical coordinates.  My guess is that since the field is *non* minimally coupled (eq 7), solutions for $\phi$ depend on the curvature, and consequently on the spin connection.  A minimally coupled scalar field would't have the curvature term, and since the other derivatives are ordinary partials, no connection would be involved.